# Seperate two pictures with black beam in imshow

Tags: python, opencv

I want to show two images and seperate them visually with a black beam in Python.
My Problem is, that I get not the original colors with the `cv2.imshow()`function in the Plot-Window.
Here is my Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

imgloc = 'path\Dosen_py.png'
img = cv2.imread(imgloc)
hight = np.shape(img)[0]
beam = np.zeros((hight,10,3))   

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray_3_channel = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

horizontal = np.hstack((img,beam,gray_3_channel))

small = cv2.resize(horizontal, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)  

cv2.imwrite("combi.png",small)

cv2.imshow("Combi",small)

cv2.waitKey()
```

After running the code i get the following picture in the plot window:
[image]

The saved "combi.png"-file shows the right colors:[image]

If I plot the two pictures without the black beam, i get the original colours,too.
Does anyone know whats wrong with this black beam?

System: Windows 10

IDE: Spyder (Python 2.7)

Answer (score 2):

The default `np.ndarray.dtype` is `np.float64`, while for image, it should be `np.uint8`.

This line:

```
beam = np.zeros((hight,10,3))
```

and then, the `beam`、`horixxx` and `small` all are `np.float64`. So you display the `float64`. But when  write,  truncated to `np.uint8`.

---

It should be changed to:

```
beam = np.zeros((hight,10,3), np.uint8)
```